# Чем отличается ППП от прикладной программы?

Tags: пакет

Чем отличается Пакет Прикладных программ от набора программ?

Comment: Пакет = несколько. В чем различие между одним апельсином и пакетом апельсинов?

Comment: В Пакете Прикладных Программ Целый Пакет, А В Прикладной Программе Только Одна Прикладная Программа

Comment: Наверное, надо спрашивать у тех, кто этот закон (или другую бумажонку) писал...

Comment: Учитывая уточнения вопроса: в пакете программы как правило объединены какой-либо общей областью применения: ппп для офисных работников (microsoft office), ппп для работы с базой данных (субд + сопутствующий софт), ппп для проектирования и т.д. В отличие от этого набор программ более общее определение.